# How to compare multiple variables in OR condition

Tags: vb.net

I have 12 variables in VB.Net.

```
If a = 1 _ Or b = 2 _ Or c = 3 _ Or d = 4 _ Or e = 5 _ Or f = 6 _ Or...... Then
```

Like That....

For that my string will be so long for 12 variables...

SO is there is any other way to compare 12 variables?

Thanks
Pankaj

Comment: If you have 50! nonstructured variables somehow dancing around in a method you must be doing something wrong. Maintenance of your code must be a nightmare. Isn't there any internal structure or relationship between your a,b,c,d or e etc. variables. If so then you should model that strucure in your application.

Comment: I'd be very curious to know in what kind of situation you would need to write such code. Maybe a little bit more context would help us do better recommandations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this.If u have this type of comarison....

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to compare a bunch of variables to a single value or evaluate an expression against them. For example if you wanted to check whether any of your variables a through z equal 10.

When you are evaluating each of them against a different constant value, however, you need the expression for each one.

You should note that your code will unnecessarily evaluate all of the expressions, when in theory it could stop checking once any of the conditions are met. For that, use `OrElse` instead of `Or`. That will, of course, make the code even longer.

One way to pare down the syntax slightly (for long condition sets):

```
Dim all = new Boolean(){ _
    a = 1, _
    b = 2, _
    c = 3, _
    d = 4, _
    e = 5, _
    }.All(Function(x As Boolean) x)
```

This again, however, results in evaluation of all conditions.